# navigator.share opens a smaller menu

Tags: javascript, web-share

I am using web share API.
This is the code

```js
navigator
  .share({
    title: document.title,
    text,
  })
```

When I click the button and the above code is called, the smaller menu for sharing is opened,
but I want the other complete menu to be opened. Currently, the bigger one is opened by manually clicking `more` button in the smaller menu which is at the last of the list

The smaller one-

[image: smaller]
[image: smaller2]

The bigger one

[image: complete menu]

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to press **More...** to see the **big menu (Share via)**; you can't do that using `navigator.share` API without user involvement.

**Share via** not possible from the browser, it's possible inside mobile applications (Android/iOS).

[image]

Again, `navigator.share` Just call the native share in Android/iOS, then the traget system handle the rest! this feature have some security concerns you can see it throw `w3.org`

https://www.w3.org/TR/web-share/#dom-navigator-share

[image]

At the end if want to share via specific app you can use [deeplinking](https://www.adjust.com/blog/dive-into-deeplinking/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({ files: filesArray })) {
  navigator.share({
    files: filesArray,
    title: 'Pictures',
    text: 'Our Pictures.',
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Share was successful.'))
  .catch((error) => console.log('Sharing failed', error));
} else {
  console.log(`Your system doesn't support sharing files.`);
}
```

Comment: I am not sharing any file. But I tried it with passing files also, but it didn't work.